# Consume @output value in another component

Tags: angular

I have a component which emits a value with `@Output` and another component where I'd like to consume that value.

How do I pass `myValue` from `OutputComponent` to `InputComponent`?

**output component**

```
export class OutputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() myValue: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  ...
}
```

**input component**

```
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
  // Use myValue here
}
```

Comment: Can you please mention if InputComponent is parent component of OutputComponent Or not.

Comment: @PiyaliDas `OutputComponent` is a child of `InputComponent`

Answer (score 3):

If the 'input-component' is the parent component:

In child.component.ts:

```
@Output() someEvent = new EventEmitter

someFunction(): void {
  this.someEvent.emit('Some data...')
}
```

In parent template:

```
<app-child (someEvent)="handleSomeEvent($event)"></app-child>
```

In parent.component.ts:

```
handleSomeEvent(event: any): void {
  // Do something (with the event data) or call any functions in the component
}
```

If it is an unrelated component you need to make a service bound to the root of the application with a Subject that you can subscibe to, from wherever in your application.

I documented on all types of data sharing between components here:

https://github.com/H3AR7B3A7/EarlyAngularProjects/tree/master/data-sharing

Comment: Link is down ...

Answer (score 0):

Components can communicate using service methods

```
export class OneService {
  public a = new Subject<Boolean>()

  oneBox(sub: boolean) {
    this.a.next(sub);
  }

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

A Component/B Component

```
  constructor(private oneService:OneService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.oneService.a.subscribe(console.log)
  }
```

triggering condition

```
    this.oneService.oneBox(true)
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try below code:

In input template (parent template) :

```
<app-Output (myValue)="emitedMyValue($event)"></app-Output>
```

In InputComponent.ts(Parent component) :

```
public emitedMyValue(item: any) {
    // use the value here
}
```

In OutputComponent.ts(Child component):

```
@Output() myValue = new EventEmitter<string>();
public myFunction(): void {
    this.myValue .emit('value');
}
```